# How to inprove and assing var and modify object property on click on checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm developing a function to create a random password and I got working rigth now, but I wan to improve some code becouse I use 3 checkbox to include caps, numbers and symbols, so I made a eventListener to one by one checkbox but I think if I use a class to all checkbox I can use a for () to iterate on each checkbox using a class and add for example a data-item="caps", data-item="nums" & data-item="syms" to get that attribute and modify my object that includes default values as true, when a user click uncheck an item add the eventListener to call my function:

this is my actual working code:

```js
let chkboxUppercase = document.querySelector('#chkboxUppercase');
let chkboxNumbers = document.querySelector('#chkboxNumbers');
let chkboxSymbols = document.querySelector('#chkboxSymbols');

let config = {
    syms: true,
    nums: true,
    caps: true,
    lows: true
}

chkboxUppercase.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    config.caps = !config.caps;
    generatePassword();
})
chkboxNumbers.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    config.nums = !config.nums;
    generatePassword();
})
chkboxSymbols.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    config.syms = !config.syms;
    generatePassword();
})

function generatePassword(){
    //... my function goes here...
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-3 custom-checkbox-container mt-3 mt-lg-0 text-center text-lg-right">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input change-checkbox" id="chkboxUppercase" data-item="caps" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkboxUppercase">Caps</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input change-checkbox" id="chkboxNumbers" data-item="nums" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkboxNumbers">Numbers</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input change-checkbox" id="chkboxSymbols" data-item="syms" checked="checked">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkboxSymbols">Symbols</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is what I'm trying to do:

```js
let chkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.change-checkbox');
for (let index = 0; index < chkBoxes.length; index++) {
    chkBoxes[index].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        let data = chkBoxes[index].getAttribute('data-item');
        config.data = !config.data;
        generatePassword();
    })
}
```

But is not working properly is just like the script is ignoring my var data...: https://prnt.sc/pd771w

If someone can make me see my mistake I would appreciate it,

Thank's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) by using `element.dataset`:

```
const chkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.change-checkbox');

const handleChange = function (e) {
  const data = e.target.dataset.item;
  config[data] = e.target.checked;
  generatePassword();
}

chkBoxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', handleChange);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I put your change on my code, and I got the same result, the problem here Is the config.data is insterting on my object a property called data instead the given on the let data = ...
http://prntscr.com/pd7deq

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix that. The bracket syntax will allow you to access object properties as strings. The dot notation does not allow that.

Comment: That's works as expectly I was trying to access to data using config.[data] but as you said that don't works, yeah I was loosing on that part thank's man!

Comment: I've refactor the code a little bit. Instead of toggling your config property you should use the `checked` property of your input elements. Also, it is better not to define functions inside a loop. And definitively use const instead of let as Jon DeWitt said.

Comment: I liked more the code that you have finally refactored, I appreciate the help and I will keep in mind the use of constants and handlers, thank's again!

Answer (score 2):

Just a general note, but I would encourage the use of `const` over `let` unless you have a very good reason to reassign values.  That aside, I would iterate over these elements with `forEach` instead, and just use that data attribute's value as the object key, like so.

```js
const checkboxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('.change-checkbox')]

const config = {
  syms: true,
  nums: true,
  caps: true,
  lows: true
}

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  const item = checkbox.dataset.item
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    config[item] = !config[item]
    generatePassword()
  })
})
```

Comment: you are right it is not necessary to use **let** since I do not want reassing those values ... I will keep it in mind, thank you very much!

Comment: Always happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the "data" property of the config object, rather than set the property corresponding to the checkbox attribute. Change the following line

```
 config.data = !config.data;
```

to the following to access the property corresponding to the data value

```
 config[data] = !config[data];
```